# MySQL multiple Inner Join help - 1064

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Maybe its just a late night or maybe I've not had enough coffee but I can't seem to make sense why my MySQL statement is 1064'ing.

[image]

PSEUDO CODE:

> Get the id of the latest event happening, then join it with all guests that are linked (attending) that event retrieving their first and second names.

MYSQL

```
SELECT event.id, link.event_id, link.guests_id, guests.id, guests.first_name, guests.second_name 
FROM event
INNER JOIN link
ON event.id =link.event_id;
INNER JOIN guests
ON link.guests_id = guest.id;
ORDER BY event.date DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `;` from the stament to make it work.

`;` is a delimiter and the DB engine thinks your query ends on `;` and is incomplete

Comment: Thanks, was still in PHP mode :)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot an "s"

on link.guests_id = guests.id